# Index out of Bounds error in a small Octave program

Tags: octave

This is the code, it just calculates two outputs based on two inputs x and y.

```
function [nextX, nextY]=newton(x,y)
nextX= x-((6*(x^2)*(y^2)*(x+y)-9*(y^2)((y^3)+14)-2*(x^2)*(5*(x^2)-69))/(x*y*(18*x*y+20)));
nextY= y-((10*(x^4)+18*x^2*(y^3)-414*(x^2)+30*x*(y^2)-420*x)/(x*y*(18*x*y+20)));
end   

[x,y]=newton(1,1)
```

I get

```
error: newton: A(I): index out of bounds; value 15 out of bound 1
error: called from:
error:   newton at line 2, column 6
```

whenever I try to run it, I'm a novice at octave and I really can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: I'm running the code using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/try_matlab.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very simple error (probably a typo) in your code here:

```
nextX= x-((6*(x^2)*(y^2)*(x+y)-9*(y^2)((y^3)+14)-2*(x^2)*(5*(x^2)-69))/(x*y*(18*x*y+20)));
                                      ^
```

There is no operator between two parentheses, so Octave assumes that you're trying to get an element of a vector/matrix by it's index, thus throwing `index out of bounds` exception.

Probably you wanted to multiply two values instead:

```
nextX= x-((6*(x^2)*(y^2)*(x+y)-9*(y^2)*((y^3)+14)-2*(x^2)*(5*(x^2)-69))/(x*y*(18*x*y+20)));
```

Comment: Thank you, I was really confused there for a moment.